# Kernel crashes when increasing iterations

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I am running a Python script using Spyder 2.3.9. I have a fairly large script and when running it through with (300x600) iterations (a loop inside another loop), everything appears to be working fine and takes approximately 40 minutes. But when I increase the number to (500x600) iterations, after 2 hours, the output yields:

```
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
```

I've been trying to go through the code but don't see anything that might be causing this in particular. I am using Python 2.7.12 64bits, Qt 4.8.7, PyQt4 (API v2) 4.11.4. (Anaconda2-4.0.0-MacOSX-x86_64)

I'm not entirely sure what additional information is pertinent, but if you have any suggestions or questions, I'd be happy to read them.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3114

It seems this issue has been opened on their GitHub profile, should be addressed soon given the repo record.

Some possible solutions:

1. It may be helpful, if possible, to modify your script for faster convergence. Very often, for most practical purposes, the incremental value of iterations after a certain point is negligible.
2. An upgrade or downgrade of the Spyder environment may help.
3. Check your local firewall for blocked connections to 127.0.0.1 from pythonw.exe.
4. If nothing works, try using Spyder on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at this. And so this appears to be an error from Spyder then? I'll try to test the code in other environments as well and return with a better idea of the problem.